# Get unique values from multiple lists in Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, list

How can I join the multiple lists in a Pandas column 'B' and get the unique values only:

```
   A   B 
0  10  [x50, y-1, sss00]
1  20  [x20, MN100, x50, sss00]
2  ...
```

Expected output:

```
[x50, y-1, sss00, x20, MN100]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in input data are not lists, but strings first create lists:

```
df.B = df.B.str.strip('[]').str.split(',')
```

Or:

```
import ast
df.B = df.B.apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

---

Use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) for one `Series` from lists with [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) for remove duplicates if order is important:

```
L = df.B.explode().unique().tolist()
#alternative
#L = df.B.explode().drop_duplicates().tolist()
```

---

```
print (L)
['x50', 'y-1', 'sss00', 'x20', 'MN100']
```

Another idea if order is not important use set comprehension with flatten lists:

```
L = list(set([y for x in df.B for y in x]))
print (L)
['x50', 'MN100', 'x20', 'sss00', 'y-1']
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, could you please briefly explain the logic?

Comment: @nilsinelabore - Added to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simply by list comprehension and `sum()` method:

```
result=[x for x in set(df['B'].sum())]
```

Now If you print result you will get your desired output:

```
['y-1', 'x20', 'sss00', 'x50', 'MN100']
```

Comment: Don't use sum to concatenate lists. It looks fancy but it's quadratic and should be considered bad practice.

Comment: ohh....ok...btw thnx @jezrael for telling this **:)**